# Creating a Network Place Folder via a script?

Tags: windows, network-share

Is it possible to create a Windows 'Network Place' folder using a script, in a similar fashion to mounting a network drive?

We have a lot of SharePoint document libraries that we would like to create an easy way to save to directly from Word or Excel, and creating lots of mapped network drives will rapidly use up drive letters.

Solved: Create a standard shortcut to the UNC path in C:\Documents And Settings\User\NetHood\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Network places is essentially just a folder of shortcuts, so creating places via script is relatively easy. See t[his scripting guy article](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/scriptcenter/resources/qanda/may05/hey0509.mspx) on how to do it.